# Can linking verbs be used instead of BE in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, linking-verbs

The window was broken.
The window got broken.
The window seemed broken.
The window ended up broken.

All these sentences look like passive voice examples to me.
But I have only found terms "passive" and "get-passive".
Can other linking verbs replace "be"?

Comment: No, they can't all be used instead of _be_. You can use _get_ for the passive, but that's the only one. The other verbs have special constructions where the _be_ is optional (that happens with very common, very old, very basic verbs like these), and so there are sentences where _be_ doesn't occur. There are also sentences where it does, because it's part of the construction. This doesn't make them alternates of _be_; even _get_ is only used instead of _be_ in the passive -- everywhere else it means something different.

Comment: *Seems* is an object-oriented verb of perception. It has an agent that doesn't appear in the sentence. This is typical. *Noticed* works in a similar manner. *End up* is just an ordinary copula here.

Answer (score 1):

The second two examples have *broken* as an adjective. The *get* example has it as a past participle, and the *be* example is ambiguous.

> The window was broken by the ball.  [past participle]
>
> The window was pretty broken. [adjective]

Try the same series with a verb that has a past participle which doesn't share a shape with an adjective.

> The window was cleaned.
>
> The window got cleaned.
>
> *The window seemed cleaned.
>
> *The window ended up cleaned.

The passive voice is made up of *be* or *get* and a past participle, whereas 'linking verbs' take a noun or adjective. *Be* can mark passive voice or serve as a 'linking verb' depending on context. *Get* can have a 'linking verb' interpretation, especially with comparatives.

> The window got smaller.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! :-)